# Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>

Tags: python, conda

My travis job hit issue of following:

```
Process Output:Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Process Output:Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Process Output:Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Process Output:Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
Process Output:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I have already tried to set PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME, but still doesn't work. Could anyone help me on that ? Thanks

```bash
export PYTHONHOME='$HOME/miniconda'
export PYTHONPATH='$HOME/miniconda:$PYTHONPATH'
```

Comment: hi @zjfdu, do you use a virtual environment?

Comment: I had this issue in a Jupyter notebook. In that case it's not the virtualenv that needs to be recreated, but the jupyter kernel

Answer (score 6):

This happens when you remove the default python libraries and don't replace it.  For example when following upgrade instructions that are less than complete.  I ran into this and solved it like this on ubuntu ( should be similar process on others )...

I installed new python using ( overuse of sudo I know ):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

$ cd /usr/src
$ sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz

$ sudo tar xzf Python-2.7.13.tgz
$ cd Python-2.7.13
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make install
```

This created a python2.7 for me in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/bin.  I then deleted the system python in /usr/lib/ thinking I don't want two versions and things broke.  Because the new python is in /usr/lib/local and the system is looking in /usr/lib/.

```
$ cd /usr/lib
$ sudo rm -rf python2.7
```

The specific error I got after deleting system python libraries was:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-httplib2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-httplib2 is already the newest version (0.8-2build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python-httplib2 (0.8-2build1) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing package python-httplib2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-httplib2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

To fix this replace the system python with your newly installed python ( I did the first two earlier but I want to show a proper python swap here ):

```
$ cd /usr/lib
$ sudo rm -rf python2.7
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7 python2.7

$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo rm python2.7
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python python2.7
```

Then things work again...

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-httplib2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-httplib2 is already the newest version (0.8-2build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python-httplib2 (0.8-2build1) ...
```

Comment: It occurred with my conda env. So I removed the env and recreated it, and the error went away

Comment: Python was broken while upgrading from `16.04` to `20.04`. This one solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove libpythonx.x first, and install python again

```
sudo apt-get remove libpython3.8-minimal
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```