# How to resolve 'Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>'

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

After upgraded Python 11 to Python 12, when I run any code, I am getting above error message.

I tried to follow the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992246/could-not-find-platform-independent-libraries-prefix), but it seems like it does not apply to my situation.

Originally all my virtual environments were stored inside the .virtualenv folder. However, in order to fix the above error, I first

> pip freeze > requirements.txt

inside every single project, and then created new virtualenv using

> python -m venv  .

after that deleted the whole .virtualenv folder from the user/admin (whatever it's called on Windows, the folder that belongs to the admin user).

since the new virtualenv inside each project was created using python12, and the default .virtualenv folder was deleted, I assumed that issue would go away. it didn't.

Is there any folder that I miss to delete?

Someone online said it happens when we created a virtualenv and deleted it, I do get that; however, I cannot restore it, nor do I know how to redo whatever I did.

I need some advice. Thank you in advance